# Compile time zero C union

Tags: c, initialization, unions

I have a union with a great number of fields, some of indeterminate size. I'd like to create a preset value (in the vein of NULL) where every field of the union is zero. I tried the following, but without optimization it would probably result in two copies; and more importantly doesn't actually work.

Header:

```
extern union MyUnion my_union_zero;
```

Source:

```
static char my_union_zero_arr[sizeof(union MyUnion)] = {0};
union MyUnion my_union_zero = (union MyUnion)my_union_zero_arr;
```

Am I missing something obvious? Is there a standard way to accomplish this?

Comment: There's no such thing as a field of indeterminate size; can you elaborate on what you mean by that?

Comment: One of the fields is an int, and the C standard only defines a minimum size for int. How would I portably find the largest union field at compile time?

Comment: I'm Assuming it has variable length arrays then.

Comment: For any given compiler, an int will have a fully determined size; it just may not be the same as that for another compiler.

Comment: "doesn't actually work": Please elaborate.

Comment: You just want to set all bits of the union to 0? `memset`?

Comment: memset would be correct, but I'm looking for the compile-time version

Comment: @user3386109 are you suggesting replace the array there with a second union?

Comment: No, although that might work. (I misread the question.) However, given that the header declares `my_union_zero` as `extern`, I presume that `my_union_zero` is a global, and globals are also compile time initialized to 0, unless otherwise explicitly initialized.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use

```
static union MyUnion my_union_zero;
```

and rely on the compiler to do all the zero-initialization.

---

After this point only legalese and history. Read on if you like.

From [n1331](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1311.pdf) paraphrazed:

1. K&R-C: Uninitialized static objects start out as 0. (Take note there is no reference to null-pointers being weird.)

   > Static and external variables which are not initialized are guaranteed to start off
   >   as 0; automatic and register variables which are not initialized are guaranteed to
   >   start off as garbage.
2. C89: All arithmetic members are initialized to 0 and all pointer-members to null-pointer. (Take note that padding was forgotten (and in this case is non-existant for `union`s anyway. Also, noone took note that null-pointers might not be all-bits-zero yet.)

   > If an object that has static storage duration is not initialized explicitly, it is
   >   initialized implicitly as if every member that has arithmetic type were assigned 0
   >   and every member that has pointer type were assigned a null pointer constant.
3. DR_016: Reminds of null-pointer being weird, which would make many `union`s ill-formed. Committee-decision that only the first member was to be initialized, which breaks many programs (though was not intended to).
4. C99: Incorporated that DR-resolution, to get:

   > - if it is a union, the first named member is initialized (recursively) according to these
   >     rules.
5. C11: Corrected that error:

   > #### 6.7.9 Initialization
   >
   > 10 If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized explicitly, its value is
   >   indeterminate. If an object that has static or thread storage duration is not initialized
   >   explicitly, then:
   >
   > - if it has pointer type, it is initialized to a null pointer;
   > - if it has arithmetic type, it is initialized to (positive or unsigned) zero;
   > - if it is an aggregate, every member is initialized (recursively) according to these rules,
   >     and any padding is initialized to zero bits;
   > - if it is a union, the first named member is initialized (recursively) according to these
   >     rules, and any padding is initialized to zero bits;

Comment: You quote C11 (n1570, I guess); C99 (n1256) differs in wording. Is this also a semantic change?

Comment: "padding" usually means bytes that are not part of any member, but you seem to be using it to mean bytes that are part of a member other than the one currently being set. A standard quote to confirm the meaning of "padding" here would be good

Comment: @mafso: Research done. It's a semantic change which is a reversion to the intended and former meaning.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: It's never explicitly defined, only used as opposite to "value-bits". And as only the last-written union-member may be read, that makes all union-bits not part of it non-value-bits. That interpretation is also covered by colloquial meaning and history.

Comment: " as only the last-written union-member may be read" is a C++ thing; C allows aliasing via unions

Comment: @Deduplicator I greatly appreciate all this research!

Comment: @MattMcNabb: Hm. Still, the bytes of the union not used by the assigned member take unspecified values, so not a big difference if any. Anyway, the reasoning does not depend on it.

Comment: "value bits" for the union could be interpreted as any bit which is a value bit for any member of the union. It seems underspecified

Comment: @MattMcNabb: Hm. That would mean they haven't succeeded in filling all the holes to make the wording match the intent. And while it is imho a bit far-fetched, that might be good enough for language-lawyers.

Comment: The initialization `union U x = { 0 };` might not be all-bits-zero (e.g. first-member is a non-IEEE floating point) , so it seems plausible that there should not be a requirement to zero any other bits

Answer (score 1):

Compiler time version would be

```
static union MyUnion my_union_zero = {
    .field1 = 0,
       .
       .
       .
    .fieldN = 0
};
```

Comment: Ugh I'll have to keep it in sync with the union then. Oh well; thanks

Comment: May be you can use the preprocessor to avoid the trouble.

Comment: Objects with static storage duration are implicitly initialized to zero.

Comment: @mafso Only the first named field in the case of a union;  so if the union's first field is not the smallest, then other fields may end up with nonzero bytes.  (I don't know of any implementation that wouldn't put the union in bss or equivalent, but the standard does leave the door ajar)

Comment: @MattMcNabb: No, the first member is zero-initialized and all padding (what that member does not use) is initialized to all-bits-zero.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: Really? That doesn't make that much sense, something must be written to that location at load time anyway, so why not require it to be all bits zero? If that's true (which is possible, though I'd be surprised), is there a guarantee that in `(union { int i; short s; }){ .i = 0, .s = 0 }` the bits not involved in the short (assuming `short < int`) won't be overwritten by the last initializer to unspecified values (otherwise the initializer of the `int` would be redundant)?

Comment: @mafso I think you are right, your last argument is very good.

Comment: @mafso the initializers are executed in the order they appear